# Android immersive mode

Tags: android, android-immersive

I want to hide navigation bar. Onyl show it if the user drugs his finger from outside to inside.
I test this code:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

  if(hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
}
```

The activity starts well and the navigation bars not appear. Buti have the next problems:
1) If a touch the screen anywhere the navigation bar is show.
2) When it's show, its not showing transparent.
3) Navigation bar never hides.

How can add this three items? What I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Add the sticky flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` to `setSystemUiVisibility` as described in the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#sticky

That way after swiping from the screen edge, navigation bars will show for some seconds and then hide again.